# "'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'labels'" error while converting Spark dataframe to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert a Spark dataframe to Pandas dataframe:

```
df_temp_p = df_temp.toPandas()
```

And I am getting below error:

```
----> 2 df_temp_p = df_temp.toPandas()

~/.conda/envs/conda_py36_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in toPandas(self)
   2122                     if len(batches) > 0:
   2123                         table = pyarrow.Table.from_batches(batches)
-> 2124                         pdf = table.to_pandas()
   2125                         pdf = _check_dataframe_convert_date(pdf, self.schema)
   2126                         return _check_dataframe_localize_timestamps(pdf, timezone)

~/.conda/envs/conda_py36_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/table.pxi in pyarrow.lib.Table.to_pandas (/arrow/python/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/lib.cxx:46331)()

~/.conda/envs/conda_py36_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py in table_to_blockmanager(options, table, memory_pool, nthreads, categoricals)
    568 
    569     # ARROW-1751: flatten a single level column MultiIndex for pandas 0.21.0
--> 570     columns = _flatten_single_level_multiindex(columns)
    571 
    572     axes = [columns, index]

~/.conda/envs/conda_py36_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py in _flatten_single_level_multiindex(index)
    626     if isinstance(index, pd.MultiIndex) and index.nlevels == 1:
    627         levels, = index.levels
--> 628         labels, = index.labels
    629 
    630         # Cheaply check that we do not somehow have duplicate column names

AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'labels'
```

I have tried multiple things like:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "false")
```

and

```
df_temp_p = df_temp.select("*").toPandas()
```

But nothing seems to be working.

P.S. This is the schema of my Spark dataframe:

```
root
 |-- decile_rank: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- oot1_count: long (nullable = false)
```

And the dataframe looks like this:

```
+-----------+----------+
|decile_rank|oot1_count|
+-----------+----------+
|          1|    169060|
|          2|    237598|
|          3|     91971|
|          4|    214923|
|          5|     38040|
|          6|    282598|
|          7|     61426|
|          8|    473339|
|          9|     36807|
|         10|    249824|
+-----------+----------+
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example of the PySpark dataframe please?

Comment: @Corralien I have updated the question with dataframe example. Is this what you asked for?

Comment: I never downvote any question and response. I think you should upgrade your current version of Python (3.6) because you probably have an old version of Pandas... Your code works perfectly fine for me. Python 3.9 and Pandas 1.5.3